# Transform Edges to Profile precisely?

Tags: modeling, add-on

i want to do this inside of blender

[image]

i already tried with transforming the edge to curve then having a rectangular extrude profile to this curve but the result is not flat , and not precise at all

is there any way i can do that inside of blender? any add-ons that can do that? if possible in a non destructive way

i also tried in extrude then solidify, this is the result i got, its already on "even thickness" im on 2.8. clearly its not precise at all, thoses angles are not straight

[image]

thanks

Comment: The closest way I know how to do this in Blender is to create the mesh, then extrude it, and then add a solidify modifier.  Extrusion is destructive but solidify is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in 279, but this works for me?

- Mesh, faces only removed, converted to **2D** Curve
- In Curve > Geometry panel 'Extrude' set to desired amount (no Bevel)
- Solidify modifier assigned, 0 Offset, Even Thickness, Fill Rim.

[image]

.. seems to render OK, but yes, if you convert back to mesh, the topology is horrible.

Comment: really nice technique and non destructive ! thanks a lot
unfortunatelly dont work on 2.8, i hope it will be fixed

Comment: @DorianBorremans  Hmm.. I wonder what's changed under the bonnet? That must be pretty fundamental, these operations are very basic.  Curves, IMO, could do with a rethink, in Blender.. Maybe they're getting one. I should know more about what's happening, but haven't used 280 enough, yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *Inset*:

[image]

1. Select the profile in Edit mode, Edge or Vertex Select mode (otherwise edges won't be selected).
2. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill all quads.
3. While they're still selected, press <kbd>I</kbd> twice to get individual inset on each face.
4. Invert selection and extrude.

Note - this approach is destructive modelling.
For non-destructive and proper solution probably node-based modelling addons could work like Sverchok or Animation Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As Marty said, a good solution should be use the solidify modifier
[image]
test and modify this code as you want

```
import bpy

tickness = 0.038
width = 0
long = 0
height = 1

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(width, long, height), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})


bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = tickness

bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Solidify")
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Comment: thanks, i edited my result with this technique on my post, its not working for me